# How do I get a certain HiveList

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

These are my models and I'm trying to save some observations related to a certain student using Hive in Flutter:

```
    @HiveType(typeId: 5)
    class Student extends HiveObject {
      @HiveField(0)
      late String firstName;

      @HiveField(1)
      late String lastName;

      @HiveField(2)
      HiveList<Observation>? observations;

      @HiveField(3)
      StudentGroup? studentGroup;

      @HiveField(4)
      Gender? gender;
    }

    @HiveType(typeId: 11)
    class Observation extends HiveObject {
      @HiveField(0)
      late String wording;

      @HiveField(1)
      late DateTime date;

      @HiveField(2)
      late Rating rating;

      @HiveField(3)
      late String subject;
    }
```

This is where I save the observations:

```
    class ObservationWidget extends StatefulWidget {
      final Student student;

      const ObservationWidget({super.key, required this.student});

      @override
      State<ObservationWidget> createState() => _ObservationWidgetState();
```

}

```
    class _ObservationWidgetState extends State<ObservationWidget> {
      Rating? _selectedRating;
      String? _selectedSubject;
      DateTime date = DateTime.now();
      late TextEditingController textController;

      void saveObservation() {
        if (_selectedRating == null || _selectedSubject == null) {
          // Todo: Add a message
          return;
        }

        final observationsBox = Boxes.getObservations();

        final newObservation = Observation()
          ..date = date
          ..rating = _selectedRating!
          ..wording = textController.text
          ..subject = _selectedSubject!;

        observationsBox.add(newObservation);
        widget.student.observations = HiveList(Boxes.getObservations());
        widget.student.observations!.add(newObservation);
        print(widget.student.observations);
        print(observationsBox.values);

        widget.student.save();

        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      }
```

And this is what the console shows after saving an observation:

flutter: [Instance of 'Observation']
flutter: (Instance of 'Observation', Instance of 'Observation', Instance of 'Observation', ..., Instance of 'Observation', Instance of 'Observation')

And here's how I try to load the student's observations:

```
    class ObservationsPage extends StatefulWidget {
      final Student student;

      const ObservationsPage({super.key, required this.student});

      @override
      State<ObservationsPage> createState() => _ObservationsPageState();
```

}

```
    class _ObservationsPageState extends State<ObservationsPage> {
      late List<Observation> studentObservations;


      @override
      void initState() {
        studentObservations = widget.student.observations ?? [];
        super.initState();
      }
```

This works fine as long as I don't restart. But when I do so, the ObservationPage doesn't show the observations anymore.

Comment: What's the specific problem/error?

Comment: I need to be able to save the observations havig something like a 'link' to the concerning student. So that later I can sort only the ones out that are linked to a certain student. Right now I can only get all of them, regardless of what student I'm looking for. So to speak I would need a separate HiveList of observations for each student object. How can I achieve that?